# How to replace objects of arrays?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Array is loaded from server. It has type `FilterModel[]`:

```js
export type FilterModel = {
    title: string;
    type: FilterType;
    collection: FilterList;
};

export type FilterList = FilterListItem[];
export type FilterListItem = {
    id: number | string;
    text: string;
    key ? : string;
    selected: boolean
};

let response: <FilterModel>[] = [];
```

Also there is default array of objects:

```js
let default: <FilterModel>[] = [];
```

If server returns empty array I should return `default`, otherwise I need to overwrite `response` over `default`.

How to do that?

```
let default = [{
    title: "1",
    type: "type1";
    collection: [{id: 1, text: "A", selected: true}, {id: 2, text: "B", selected: true}]
}];

let response = [{
    title: "1",
    type: "type1";
    collection: [{id: 1, text: "A", selected: false}, {id: 2, text: "B", selected: true}]
}];

let expected = [{
    title: "1",
    type: "type1";
    collection: [{id: 1, text: "A", selected: false}, {id: 2, text: "B", selected: true}]
}];
```

**let is simplify it:**

I have a fixes list of objects that I should display on the page:

```
let list = [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 2, name: "B", {id: 3, name: "C"}}];
```

I save this list on the server. Second time I get this list back.

Sometimes I can save not full list, but part:

```
 let list2 = [{id: 1, name: "A", selected: true}, {id: 2, name: "B", selected: true}];
```

In this case when I get `list2` from server I must merge with `list` and get full list with modification. So `list` always has stricted number of object, but they can be modified.

**Last edit:**

```
let response = {
  "filters": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "selected": true,
      "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}]
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "selected": true,
      "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}]
    }
  ]
};

let def = [
   {
      "name": "A",
      "selected": false,
      "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: false}]
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "selected": true,
      "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: false}]
    }
];

def.forEach((filterDef) => {
  response.filters.forEach((filter) => {
         if(filterDef.name === filter.name) {
            filterDef = filter;
         }
  });
});

console.log(def);
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking

Comment: Okay I will add an example

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you want to merge the arrays or just replace the server array when it is empty?

Comment: Ok so you want to merge two identical structures of objects and array?

Comment: Fixed, look at question, I have repository of filters, user can select them after save. Saved filters returns from server and should override existing default filters;

Comment: Yes, you are right, may be I need change structure, I doubt

Comment: `type: "type1";` i think there should be `type: "type1",` . And I'm didn't get the question too for now.

Comment: `expected = response.length > 0 ? response : default`?

Comment: `let list = [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 2, name: "B", {id: 3, name: "C"}}];` do you really mean nested objects or this is another typo (as with `;`)?

Comment: I did not get you, I have a fixed list, user can select on of object in this list and save. So next time when I get data from server I get modified array of objects with selected property to know which objects were selected last time.

Comment: I have added a simple version what I try to do

Comment: Could you check my remark?

Comment: Alice, not sure if it makes sense at all, but anyway: do you mean the three objects in the `list` like this {1} {2} {3} or like this {1} {2{3}} ?

Comment: Only like this `{1} {2} {3}`, it is just array of objects fixed by lenght, but can be modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution (I hope):

```js
let response = {
"filters": [
    {
    "name": "A",
    "selected": true,
    "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}]
    },
    {
    "name": "B",
    "selected": true,
    "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}]
    }
]
};

let def = [
{
    "name": "A",
    "selected": false,
    "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: false}]
    },
    {
    "name": "B",
    "selected": true,
    "collection": [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: false}]
    }
];

def.forEach((filterDef, i) => {               // <--- add a counter
    response.filters.forEach((filter) => {
        if (filterDef.name === filter.name) {
            def[i] = filter;                  // <--- get the object via the counter
        }
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(def));
```

Not sure if it can be considered as an optimal solution, but it works.

Instead of a couple `forEach()` and the clumsy counter you can use this magic spell:

```
def = def.map(filterDef => 
   { return response.filters.filter(f => (f.name == filterDef.name)) ?? filterDef }
);
```

If for some reason you have no soul and you like this fancy style. )

Comment: Keep in mind that the `def[i] = filter` _replaces_ the 'def' object with the object from 'response.filters' (with the same 'name'). If you need to _update_ the 'def' object (or/and its 'collection') you have to make additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

1: Using splice() method. The array type in JavaScript provides us with splice() method that helps us in order to replace the items of an existing array by removing and inserting new elements at the required/desired index. ...
2: Using array map() and filter() methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the structure and retrieve the right values with a recursive function like this:

```js
let defaultData = [{
    title: "1",
    type: "type1",
    collection: [{id: 1, text: "A", selected: true}, {id: 2, text: "B", selected: true}]
}];

let response = [{
    title: "1",
    type: "type1",
    collection: [{id: 1, text: "B"}, {id: 2, text: "B", selected: true}]
}];

function overwrite(defaultData, override) {
  if(override instanceof Object) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(override).map(x => [x, overwrite(defaultData[x], override[x])]));
  }
  if(override instanceof Array) {
    return override.map(x => overwrite(defaultData.find(({ id }) => id === x.id), override[i]));
  }
  
  return override ?? defaultData;
}

console.log(overwrite(defaultData, response));
```

Comment: Let me expalin again, I have default array of objects `FilterModel`. Any element of array (object) can be modified. After all it can be saved.

Comment: Response data shoud be equal of default,but not less

Comment: I have added a simple version what I try to do

Comment: As far as I can tell, in the function `forEach()` you need to use a counter. I'll add new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for the simplified task is here:

```js
let list = [
    {id: 1, name: "A"},
    {id: 2, name: "B"},
    {id: 3, name: "C"}
    ];

let list2 = [
    {id: 1, name: "A", selected: true},
    {id: 2, name: "B", selected: true}
    ];

for (var i=0; i<list2.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<list.length; j++) {
        if (list[j].id == list2[i].id) { 
            list[j] = {...list[j], ...list2[i]} // or simply list[j] = list2[i]
        }
    }
}

console.log(list);
```

Output:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'A', selected: true },
  { id: 2, name: 'B', selected: true },
  { id: 3, name: 'C' }
]
```

Just stupid loops through all objects within the arrays.

---

Instead of the loops you can use `forEach()` function:

```js
let list = [
    {id: 1, name: "A"},
    {id: 2, name: "B"},
    {id: 3, name: "C"}
    ];

let list2 = [
    {id: 1, name: "A", selected: true},
    {id: 2, name: "B", selected: true}
    ];

list2.forEach( (obj, i) => 
    { if (obj.id == list[i].id) list[i] = {...list[i], ...obj} });

console.log(list);
```

---

Solution could look a little bit cleaner if you modify a design of your data this way:

```js
let list = {
    id1: {name: "A"},
    id2: {name: "B", some: "xxx"},
    id3: {name: "C"}
    };

let list2 = {
    id1: {name: "A", selected: true},
    id2: {name: "B", selected: true}
    };

for (id in list2) list[id] = {...list[id], ...list2[id]} 
   
console.log(list);
```

So you don't need to search every time the objects with some id among the rest of objects. You can refer any object directly by its id: `list.id1` or `list['id1']`.

Comment: Yes, that what I need, thank you, how do you solve the same logic in yours applications? Maybe my way initially is wrong?

Comment: I'd try to modify the data a bit. Probably it should be an object with `id`s inside instead of the list of noname objects. See my updated answer.

Comment: Check my question please